# MAAS maas-import-pxe-files

Tags: juju, proxy, maas

I'm experiencing this issue on a fresh maas install behind a proxy.

```
sudo http_proxy=http://myname:mypass@192.45.0.2:3128 maas-import-pxe-files

2015-05-21 13:28:41,236 INFO Importing boot resources.
2015-05-21 13:28:41,255 ERROR Unhandled exception; unable to continue.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/maas-import-pxe-files", line 30, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/provisioningserver/import_images/boot_resources.py", line 493, in main
    repo_boot = dumper.dump(source['path'], keyring=source['keyring'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/provisioningserver/import_images/boot_resources.py", line 276, in dump
    super(RepoDumper, self).sync(reader, rpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplestreams/mirrors/__init__.py", line 82, in sync
    content, payload = reader.read_json(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplestreams/mirrors/__init__.py", line 40, in read_json
    return raw, self.policy(content=raw, path=path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplestreams/util.py", line 254, in policy_read_signed
    return read_signed(content=content, keyring=keyring)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplestreams/util.py", line 299, in read_signed
    raise SignatureMissingException("No signature found!")
SignatureMissingException: No signature found!
```

I also tried this :

```
maas useromc maas set-config name=http_proxy value=http://myname:mypass@192.45.0.2:3128
{"http_proxy": ["Enter a valid URL."]}
```

No way to download those pxe files ...
Any advice is welcome !

Comment: yes I'm behind a proxy and have to provide a username/pass

Comment: It seems that the python tries to read a dict from /etc/maas/bootresources.yaml. keyring: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-cloudimage-keyring.gpg. The key seems to be ok on my server ...

Comment: maas useromc maas set-config name=http_proxy value=http://192.45.0.2:3128 works fine, it seems that I cannot provide a username/password for my proxy :/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are experiencing an issue related with proxy authentication, Here is a simple way to set proxy authentication in Ubuntu:

Here is a link to a python program named UBPROXY . Given below are the steps to set proxy Authentication.

http://code.google.com/p/ubproxy/downloads/detail?name=ubproxy

command to use->

1.download this program.

2.open your terminal

3."cd ~/Downloads" (Presuming that your download exist in this directory)

4."chmod +x ubproxy"

5."sudo ./ubproxy"

Comment: Well thanks but exporting http_proxy should be enough I guess... and I have no desktop